# convert to local time zone using latitude and longitude?

Tags: r, timezone

I have a data set with the following information: latitude, longitude, EST time. For example, for one observation

```
lat = 13
long = -2
time1 = as.POSIXlt("2014-02-12 17:00:00", tz = "EST")
```

I want to create a new variable timeL that is the local time. Any suggestions of how to do this with R?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
lat = 13
long = -2
time1 <- as.POSIXct("2014-02-12 17:00:00", tz = "EST")
# https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/
apiurl <- sprintf("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/%s?location=%s,%s&timestamp=%d&sensor=%s", 
                  "xml", 
                  lat, 
                  long, 
                  as.numeric(time1), 
                  "false")
library(XML)
tz <- xmlParse(readLines(apiurl))[["string(//time_zone_id)"]]
as.POSIXct(format(time1, tz=tz))
# [1] "2014-02-12 22:00:00 CET"
```

or, as suggested by @SymbolixAU, use their [`googleway`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleway/index.html) package:

```
res <- googleway::google_timezone(c(lat, long), time1, key = NULL)
as.POSIXct(format(time1, tz=res$timeZoneId))
# [1] "2014-02-12 22:00:00 CET"
```

Comment: there's also the API wrapper `google_timezone()` in my `googleway` pacakge that avoids having to parse the XML yourself.

Comment: With lat = 114 I get tz = "", why?

Comment: @Claudia What tz would you expect?

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution, but for some reason the output is GMT, even though my coordinates are Lat - 3, Lon 160. I have tried both solutions:  `time1 <- as.POSIXct("2015-10-30 03:50:00", tz = "UTC")` 
   `res <- googleway::google_timezone(c(-3, 162), time1, key = NULL)`
 `as.POSIXct(format(time1, tz=res$timeZoneId))`

Answer (score 4):

An alternate approach is to intersect the target point coordinates with a shapefile of global time zones and subsequently convert the EST timestamps to the local time at each spatial  point. For example, boundaries of the world's time zones are available from [Timezone Boundary Builder](https://github.com/evansiroky/timezone-boundary-builder) ([direct download](https://github.com/evansiroky/timezone-boundary-builder/releases/download/2018d/timezones.geojson.zip)).

```
library(sf)

## example data
dat = data.frame(lon = -2
                 , lat = 13
                 , time1 = as.POSIXlt("2014-02-12 17:00:00", tz = "EST"))

## convert to 'sf' object
sdf = st_as_sf(dat, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)

## import timezones (after extraction) and intersect with spatial points
tzs = st_read("timezones.geojson/combined.json", quiet = TRUE)
sdf = st_join(sdf, tzs)

## convert timestamps to local time
sdf$timeL = as.POSIXlt(sdf$time1, tz = as.character(sdf$tzid))
sdf$timeL
# [1] "2014-02-12 22:00:00 GMT"
```

Note that the corresponding time zone [Africa/Ouagadougou](https://www.zeitverschiebung.net/de/timezone/africa--ouagadougou) is GMT.

Comment: Instead of doing a full `st_intersection` you could also use `st_join` (just replace in the code) to joint the timezone attributes to the point. For this example this may not relevant, but `st_join` is usually much faster for larger data sets and for point-in-polygon queries produces identical results.

Comment: Agreed, thanks for pointing this out. See also [Vectorize `st_intersection`](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/575) issue on GitHub.