# Using latitude and longitude to generate timezone

Tags: r, xml, google-maps, timezone

I have about 9 million records with latitude and longitude, in addition to the timestamp in EST. I want to use the latitude and longitude to generate the appropriate regional timezone, from which I then want to adjust all these times for the relevant timezone.

I have tried using geonames

```
data_raw$tz <- mapply(GNtimezone, data$lat,data$lon)
```

However, this returns the following error:

```
Error in getJson("timezoneJSON", list(lat = lat, lng = lng, radius = 0)) : 
error code 13 from server: ERROR: canceling statement due to statement timeout
```

I have tried to use a method described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414340/convert-to-local-time-zone-using-latitude-and-longitude).

```
data$tz_url <- sprintf("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/%s?location=%s,%s&timestamp=%d&sensor=%s", 
              "xml", 
              data$lat, 
              data$lon, 
              as.numeric(data$time), 
              "false")

for(i in 1:100){
  data$tz[i] <- xmlParse(readLines(data$tz_url[i]), isURL=TRUE)[["string(//time_zone_name)"]]
}
```

With this method, I am able to get the urls for the XML data. But when I try to pull the XML data in a for loop, and append the timezone to the dataframe, it doesn't do it for all the records... (in fact, only 10 records at a time intermittently).

Does anyone know of any alternate methods or packages to get the three character timezone (i.e. EST) for about 9 million records relatively quickly? Your help is much appreciated. Or better yet, if you have ideas on why the code I used above isn't working, I'd appreciate that too.

Comment: If you are looking for a generlized time zone, are you considered calculating it from longitude?  360 degrees by 24 hours.  It could be close enough depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

For a list of methods of converting latitude and longitude to time zone, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16086964/634824).  These mechanisms will return the IANA/Olson time zone identifier, such as `America/Los_Angeles`.

However, you certainly don't want to make 9 million individual HTTP calls.  You should attempt to group the records to distinct locations to minimize the number of lookups.  If they are truly random, then you will still have a large number of locations, so you should consider the offline mechanisms described in the previous post (i.e. using the [tz_world](http://efele.net/maps/tz/world/) shapefile with some sort of [geospatial lookup mechanism](https://www.google.com/#q=r%20geospatial%20library)).

Once you have the IANA/Olson time zone identifier for the location, you can then use R's time zone functionality (`as.POSIXct`, `format`, etc.) with each of corresponding timestamp to obtain the abbreviation.

However, do recognize that time zone abbreviations themselves [can be somewhat ambiguous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations).  They are useful for human readability, but not much else.

Comment: So I guess there aren't any ideas for tz_world in R? I saw your other post, but there's nothing there regarding using the shapefile in R.

Comment: I haven't seen one.  Doesn't mean it isn't out there somewhere.  You can still use that technique, you'll just have to figure out how to use one of the R geospatial libraries, such as rgdal.

Answer (score 1):

I've written the package [**googleway**](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway) to access google maps API. You'll need a valid API key (and, for Google to handle 9 million calls you'll have to pay for it as their free one only covers 2500)

```
library(googleway)

key <- "your_api_key"

google_timezone(location = c(-37, 144),
                key = key)


$dstOffset
[1] 0

$rawOffset
[1] 36000

$status
[1] "OK"

$timeZoneId
[1] "Australia/Hobart"

$timeZoneName
[1] "Australian Eastern Standard Time"
```